# python os.system error handling using bcp

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, bcp, os.system

I used os.system to update a table in my SQL database, the code works and the table is updated without any error but the os.system returns 1 (there was an error), is there anything I am missing?.

I tried to run it with subprocess, but it doesn't finish the task after the tables where updated.

I wrote 
    BCP [database.table] in [path file] -f[path format] -[database] -T -o[file.log]